# Lazy Cartesian product of arrays (arbitrary nested loops)

Tags: javascript

*There are other questions about this [in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536833/arbitrary-number-of-nested-loops) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6497058/lazy-cartesian-product-of-multiple-sequences-sequence-of-sequences) [languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321906/lazy-cartesian-product-of-several-seqs-in-scala), and other [non-lazy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266402/whats-a-good-mathematical-sets-implementation-in-javascript/5626737#5626737) [JavaScript versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796678/javascript-golf-cartesian-product), but no lazy JavaScript versions that I have found.*

Given an array of an arbitrary number of arbitrary-sized arrays:

```
var sets = [ [2,3,4,5], ['sweet','ugly'], ['cats','dogs','hogs'] ];
```

and a callback function:

```
function holla( n, adj, noun ){
  console.log( [n,adj,noun].join(' ') );
}
```

what's an elegant way to iterate the entire product space *without creating a huge array of all possible combinations first*?

```
lazyProduct( sets, holla );
// 2 sweet cats
// 2 sweet dogs
// 2 sweet hogs
// 2 ugly cats
// 2 ugly dogs
// 2 ugly hogs
// 3 sweet cats
// 3 sweet dogs
// 3 sweet hogs
// 3 ugly cats
// 3 ugly dogs
// 3 ugly hogs
// 4 sweet cats
// 4 sweet dogs
// 4 sweet hogs
// 4 ugly cats
// 4 ugly dogs
// 4 ugly hogs
// 5 sweet cats
// 5 sweet dogs
// 5 sweet hogs
// 5 ugly cats
// 5 ugly dogs
// 5 ugly hogs
```

---

Note that these combinations are the same as the results you would get if you had nested loops:

```
var counts     = [2,3,4,5];
var adjectives = ['sweet','ugly'];
var animals    = ['cats','dogs','hogs'];
for (var i=0;i<counts.length;++i){
  for (var j=0;j<adjectives.length;++j){
    for (var k=0;k<animals.length;++k){
      console.log( [ counts[i], adjectives[j], animals[k] ].join(' ') );
    }
  }
}
```

The benefits of the Cartesian product are:

1. It lets you nest an arbitrary number of loops (perhaps you don't know how many items you'll iterate)
2. It lets you change the order of looping (e.g. loop by adjectives first) without having to edit your code or write out all possible combinations of looping order.

---

### Benchmarks

You can see the benchmarks for the answers below here:
http://jsperf.com/lazy-cartesian-product/26

Comment: Curiousity: Why did you ask this question?

Comment: @RobW Because I needed it and couldn't find it. Specifically, my [distinct color generator](http://phrogz.net/css/distinct-colors.html) is in the process of getting the ability to use either HSV or Lab, and to iterate those axis in arbitrary order (which makes a difference to the algorithm), and I didn't want to hand-write 12 different sets of 3-nested-for-loops. And now that I've written it, I'm not convinced that my implementation is the most elegant. :)

Comment: Lazy cartesian product, power-set, permutations and combinations are implemented in the js-combinatorics module: https://github.com/dankogai/js-combinatorics

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Coincidentally working on the same thing over the weekend. I was looking to find alternative implementations to my `[].every`-based algo which turned out to have abyssmal performance in Firefox (but screams in Chrome -- more than twice as fast as the next).

The end result is http://jsperf.com/lazy-cartesian-product/19 . It's similar to Tomalak's approach but there is only one arguments array which is mutated as the carets move instead of being generated each time.

I'm sure it could be improved further by using the clever maths in the other algos. I don't quite understand them though, so I leave it to others to try.

EDIT: the actual code, same interface as Tomalak's. I like this interface because it could be `break`ed anytime. It's only slightly slower than if the loop is inlined in the function itself.

```
var xp = crossProduct([
  [2,3,4,5],['angry','happy'], 
  ['monkeys','anteaters','manatees']]);
while (xp.next()) xp.do(console.log, console);
```

```js
function crossProduct(sets) {
  var n = sets.length, carets = [], args = [];

  function init() {
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      carets[i] = 0;
      args[i] = sets[i][0];
    }
  }

  function next() {
    if (!args.length) {
      init();
      return true;
    }
    var i = n - 1;
    carets[i]++;
    if (carets[i] < sets[i].length) {
      args[i] = sets[i][carets[i]];
      return true;
    }
    while (carets[i] >= sets[i].length) {
      if (i == 0) {
        return false;
      }
      carets[i] = 0;
      args[i] = sets[i][0];
      carets[--i]++;
    }
    args[i] = sets[i][carets[i]];
    return true;
  }

  return {
    next: next,
    do: function (block, _context) {
      return block.apply(_context, args);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Very nice. I'm going to give you the accept for the raw speed, and for including an optional context for the callback application. Why do you check for `args.length` each call to `next()` instead of guaranteeing to run `init()` once upon construction?

Comment: If you're interested, see my answer for a way to perform random lazy access into the product.

Comment: It's because I needed the first call to `next()` to not increment the last caret. It could have also been solved by doing the initialization outside and setting the last caret to -1. But never mind that, I see that you've improved your second implementation by a lot! Well done, I was avoiding recursion because I thought that was what slowed down my first algo, but yours is actually way faster!

Comment: Ah, makes sense. Yeah, the idea that you can re-use the same array for every set of params really sped up the recursive version. :)

Comment: +1 FWIW, here's a performance comparison against several variations of my implementation: http://jsperf.com/lazycartesianiterator/2. Nice work!

Answer (score 7):

A combination of recursion and iteration will do the job.

```
function lazyProduct(sets, holla) {
    var setLength = sets.length;
    function helper(array_current, set_index) {
        if (++set_index >= setLength) {
            holla.apply(null, array_current);
        } else {
            var array_next = sets[set_index];
            for (var i=0; i<array_next.length; i++) {
                helper(array_current.concat(array_next[i]), set_index);
            }
        }
    }
    helper([], -1);
}
```

### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nV2XU/

```
var sets = [ [2,3,4,5], ['sweet','ugly'], ['cats','dogs','hogs'] ];
function holla( n, adj, noun ){
  console.log( [n,adj,noun].join(' ') );
}

lazyProduct(sets,holla);
```

Comment: My method is faster than the other one :) See this **benchmark: http://jsperf.com/lazy-cartesian-product-of-arrays-arbitrary-nested-loops**

Comment: +1 Nice. I like the use of the helper function way more than re-using the function itself. And it [performs comparably to mine](http://jsperf.com/lazy-cartesian-product).

Comment: Heh, amusing that we both JSPerf'd it, and weird that we got such different results. Perhaps the performance characteristics vary based on the size and number of arrays?

Comment: I'm actually surprised that this ever performs faster than mine, or even comparably, since mine uses a total of 13 recursing function calls (on the supplied test set) while this answer uses 37 calls. (Well, compared to my first version; my second version is now winning :)

Answer (score 5):

Here's my solution, using recursion. I'm not fond of the fact that it creates an empty array on the first pass, or that it uses the `if` inside the `for` loop (instead of unrolling the test into two loops for speed, at the expense of DRYness) but at least it's sort of terse:

```
function lazyProduct(arrays,callback,values){
  if (!values) values=[];
  var head = arrays[0], rest = arrays.slice(1), dive=rest.length>0;
  for (var i=0,len=head.length;i<len;++i){
    var moreValues = values.concat(head[i]);
    if (dive) lazyProduct(rest,callback,moreValues);
    else      callback.apply(this,moreValues);
  }
}
```

Seen in action: http://jsfiddle.net/RRcHN/

---

**Edit**: Here's a far faster version, roughly [2x–10x](http://jsperf.com/lazy-cartesian-product/26) faster than the above:

```
function lazyProduct(sets,f,context){
  if (!context) context=this;
  var p=[],max=sets.length-1,lens=[];
  for (var i=sets.length;i--;) lens[i]=sets[i].length;
  function dive(d){
    var a=sets[d], len=lens[d];
    if (d==max) for (var i=0;i<len;++i) p[d]=a[i], f.apply(context,p);
    else        for (var i=0;i<len;++i) p[d]=a[i], dive(d+1);
    p.pop();
  }
  dive(0);
}
```

Instead of creating custom arrays for each recursive call it re-uses a single array (`p`) for all params. It also lets you pass in a context argument for the function application.

---

**Edit 2**: If you need random access into your Cartesian product, including the ability to perform iteration in reverse, you can use this:

```
function LazyProduct(sets){
  for (var dm=[],f=1,l,i=sets.length;i--;f*=l){ dm[i]=[f,l=sets[i].length] }
  this.length = f;
  this.item = function(n){
    for (var c=[],i=sets.length;i--;)c[i]=sets[i][(n/dm[i][0]<<0)%dm[i][1]];
    return c;
  };
};

var axes=[[2,3,4],['ugly','sappy'],['cats','dogs']];
var combos = new LazyProduct(axes);

// Iterating in reverse order, for fun and profit
for (var i=combos.length;i--;){
  var combo = combos.item(i);
  console.log.apply(console,combo);
}
//-> 4 "sappy" "dogs"
//-> 4 "sappy" "cats"
//-> 4 "ugly" "dogs"
...
//-> 2 "ugly" "dogs"
//-> 2 "ugly" "cats"
```

Decoding the above, the *n*th combination for the Cartesian product of arrays `[a,b,...,x,y,z]` is:

```
[
  a[ Math.floor( n / (b.length*c.length*...*y.length*z.length) ) % a.length ],
  b[ Math.floor( n / (c.length*...*x.length*y.length*z.length) ) % b.length ],
  ...
  x[ Math.floor( n / (y.length*z.length) ) % x.length ],
  y[ Math.floor( n / z.length ) % y.length ],
  z[ n % z.length ],
]
```

*You can see a pretty version of the above formula [on my website](http://phrogz.net/lazy-cartesian-product).*

The dividends and moduli can be precalculated by iterating the sets in reverse order:

```
var divmod = [];
for (var f=1,l,i=sets.length;i--;f*=l){ divmod[i]=[f,l=sets[i].length] }
```

With this, looking up a particular combination is a simple matter of mapping the sets:

```
// Looking for combination n
var combo = sets.map(function(s,i){
  return s[ Math.floor(n/divmod[i][0]) % divmod[i][1] ];
});
```

For pure speed and forward iteration, however, see the accepted answer. Using the above technique—even if we precalculate the list of dividends and moduli once—is 2-4x slower than that answer.

Answer (score 5):

I've created this solution:

```
function LazyCartesianIterator(set) {
  var pos = null, 
      len = set.map(function (s) { return s.length; });

  this.next = function () {
    var s, l=set.length, p, step;
    if (pos == null) {
      pos = set.map(function () { return 0; });
      return true;
    }
    for (s=0; s<l; s++) {
      p = (pos[s] + 1) % len[s];
      step = p > pos[s];
      if (s<l) pos[s] = p;
      if (step) return true;
    }
    pos = null;
    return false;
  };

  this.do = function (callback) { 
    var s=0, l=set.length, args = [];
    for (s=0; s<l; s++) args.push(set[s][pos[s]]);
    return callback.apply(set, args);
  };
}
```

It's used like this:

```
var iter = new LazyCartesianIterator(sets);
while (iter.next()) iter.do(callback);
```

It seems to work well but it is not very thoroughly tested, tell me if you find bugs.

See how it compares: http://jsperf.com/lazy-cartesian-product/8

Comment: Very interesting, thanks for sharing. Although I normally hate iterators, I like how easy this makes it to stop iteration in the middle, using a return value from the callback. I've run the tests across Chrome/Safari/FF/Opera under OS X, both on [your benchmark](http://jsperf.com/lazy-cartesian-product/2) and one [modified to use strings](http://jsperf.com/lazy-cartesian-product/3). The performance variations across browsers is astonishing!

Comment: @Phrogz I thought being able to stop the iteration in the middle of things was the whole point of laziness. ;) Anyway, for some reason this is shamefully slow on my Firefox 9 and overall much too complex in comparison. It also fails if the set contains empty arrays.

Comment: @Phrogz I've managed to squeeze out a little more on Chrome by [caching the array lengths](http://jsperf.com/lazy-cartesian-product/7), but on the other browsers it's still sluggish. I suspect `array.map()` is responsible. For some reason jsPerf also does not seem to register benchmark results properly - at least my runs do not show up in the graph. Any idea why that is?

Comment: Nice approach. In Chrome, this is the fastest method of all listed ones. In all other browsers, it's as fast/slower than the other methods. I guess that your code can be (much) faster when you move `"do"` to the while's body, and move `reset` to `next` (since it's used only once). Using comments in a good way will still keep your code readable, while you're eliminating two function calls per iteration.

Comment: @RobW Moving `do` to the body of `while` IMO breaks usability. Also, reset is only called once per iteration, this certainly has no influence on overall speed. Anyway, there probably are ways to improve this, if you want go ahead and give it a try. I'll give it some more thought, too

Comment: @RobW I've streamlined the code a bit, now using a proper object. Nevertheless, [it only runs fast in Chrome](http://jsperf.com/lazy-cartesian-product/8). I think `next()` could be made a little smarter, the for loop is wasting time.

Comment: `set.length` is considered constant during the loop, so you can cache that as well. I +1'd for the creative approach.

Comment: @RobW Thanks. :) If you have an idea how to improve `next()`, I'd appreciate it. The "try until you find an index to increment"-approach is a little dumb for my taste. I was under the impression that `array.length` is O1 anyway, so there is probably not much to gain, or is there?

Comment: @Tomalak It should [not matter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8452317/do-loops-check-the-array-length-each-time-when-comparing-i-against-array-length) in modern browsers, such as Chrome.