# Cartesian product of multiple arrays in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, cartesian-product

How would you implement the Cartesian product of multiple arrays in JavaScript?

As an example,

```
cartesian([1, 2], [10, 20], [100, 200, 300])
```

should return

```
[
  [1, 10, 100],
  [1, 10, 200],
  [1, 10, 300],
  [2, 10, 100],
  [2, 10, 200]
  ...
]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find all combinations of options in a loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12152409/find-all-combinations-of-options-in-a-loop)

Comment: This implemented in the js-combinatorics module: http://github.com/dankogai/js-combinatorics

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generating combinations from n arrays with m elements](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15298912/1048572)

Comment: I agree about underscore.js but I'm not sure I see how removing functional-programming tag will help @le_m

Comment: Fwiw, d3 added `d3.cross(a, b[, reducer])` in February. https://github.com/d3/d3-array#cross

Comment: If you’re looking for a “concatenated” variant of the cartesian product, i.e. `[ "110100", "110200", "110300", "120100",`…`, "220300" ]`, see [How can I create every combination possible for the contents of two arrays?](/q/8936610/4642212).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding All Combinations (Cartesian product) of JavaScript array values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331092/finding-all-combinations-cartesian-product-of-javascript-array-values)

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Here is a functional solution to the problem (without any **mutable variable**!) using `reduce` and `flatten`, provided by `underscore.js`:

```js
function cartesianProductOf() {
    return _.reduce(arguments, function(a, b) {
        return _.flatten(_.map(a, function(x) {
            return _.map(b, function(y) {
                return x.concat([y]);
            });
        }), true);
    }, [ [] ]);
}

// [[1,3,"a"],[1,3,"b"],[1,4,"a"],[1,4,"b"],[2,3,"a"],[2,3,"b"],[2,4,"a"],[2,4,"b"]]
console.log(cartesianProductOf([1, 2], [3, 4], ['a']));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.9.1/underscore.js"></script>
```

Remark: This solution was inspired by http://cwestblog.com/2011/05/02/cartesian-product-of-multiple-arrays/

Comment: There is a typo in this answer, there shouldn't be a ", true" (maybe lodash has changed since you made this post?)

Comment: @ChrisJefferson the second param to `flatten` is to make the flattening shallow. It is mandatory here!

Comment: Sorry, this is a lodash / underscore incompatibility, they swapped around the flag.

Comment: So when flattening, use `true` with [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#flatten) and use `false` with [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#flatten) to ensure shallow flattening.

Comment: How do modify this function so it would accept array of arrays?

Comment: Why is "map, map, flatten" better than a double forEach? It seems more convoluted. Mutability? I am probably going to upset a lot of functional programmers here, but why does mutability matter if the array you are building is local to the reduce call?

Comment: @clocksmith mutability is not "holy" and your remark is very relevant. The point of my answer was to demonstrate an elegant, idiomatic functional solution to this complex problem. The double forEach solution is probably more efficient.

Comment: @viebel playing devil's advocate to my previous comment, lodash has a "flatMap" which could make this slightly more elegant, but I don't think underscore does =(

Answer (score 232):

## 2020 Update: 1-line (!) answer with vanilla JS

**Original 2017 Answer: 2-line answer with vanilla JS:**
*(see updates below)*

All of the answers here are **overly complicated**, most of them take 20 lines of code or even more.

This example uses just **two lines of vanilla JavaScript**, no lodash, underscore or other libraries:

```
let f = (a, b) => [].concat(...a.map(a => b.map(b => [].concat(a, b))));
let cartesian = (a, b, ...c) => b ? cartesian(f(a, b), ...c) : a;
```

#### Update:

This is the same as above but improved to strictly follow the [Airbnb JavaScript Style Guide](http://airbnb.io/javascript/) - validated using [ESLint](http://eslint.org/) with [eslint-config-airbnb-base](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-config-airbnb-base):

```
const f = (a, b) => [].concat(...a.map(d => b.map(e => [].concat(d, e))));
const cartesian = (a, b, ...c) => (b ? cartesian(f(a, b), ...c) : a);
```

Special thanks to **ZuBB** for letting me know about linter problems with the original code.

#### Update 2020:

Since I wrote this answer we got even better builtins, that can finally let us reduce (no pun intended) the code to just 1 line!

```
const cartesian =
  (...a) => a.reduce((a, b) => a.flatMap(d => b.map(e => [d, e].flat())));
```

Special thanks to **inker** for suggesting the use of reduce.

Special thanks to **Bergi** for suggesting the use of the newly added flatMap.

Special thanks to **[ECMAScript 2019](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/js-es2019)** for adding flat and flatMap to the language!

### Example

This is the exact example from your question:

```
let output = cartesian([1,2],[10,20],[100,200,300]);
```

### Output

This is the output of that command:

```
[ [ 1, 10, 100 ],
  [ 1, 10, 200 ],
  [ 1, 10, 300 ],
  [ 1, 20, 100 ],
  [ 1, 20, 200 ],
  [ 1, 20, 300 ],
  [ 2, 10, 100 ],
  [ 2, 10, 200 ],
  [ 2, 10, 300 ],
  [ 2, 20, 100 ],
  [ 2, 20, 200 ],
  [ 2, 20, 300 ] ]
```

### Demo

See demos on:

- [JS Bin with Babel](http://jsbin.com/vihibelome/edit?js,console) (for old browsers)
- [JS Bin without Babel](http://jsbin.com/siwefuqina/edit?js,console) (for modern browsers)

### Syntax

The syntax that I used here is nothing new.
My example uses the spread operator and the rest parameters - features of JavaScript defined in the 6th edition of the ECMA-262 standard published on June 2015 and developed much earlier, better known as ES6 or ES2015. See:

- http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator

The new methods from the Update 2020 example was added in ES2019:

- http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap

It makes code like this so simple that it's a sin not to use it. For old platforms that don't support it natively you can always use Babel or other tools to transpile it to older syntax - and in fact my example transpiled by Babel is still shorter and simpler than most of the examples here, but it doesn't really matter because the output of transpilation is not something that you need to understand or maintain, it's just a fact that I found interesting.

### Conclusion

There's no need to write hundred of lines of code that is hard to maintain  and there is no need to use entire libraries for such a simple thing, when two lines of vanilla JavaScript can easily get the job done. As you can see it really pays off to use modern features of the language and in cases where you need to support archaic platforms with no native support of the modern features you can always use **Babel**, **TypeScript** or other tools to transpile the new syntax to the old one.

### Don't code like it's 1995

JavaScript evolves and it does so for a reason. TC39 does an amazing job of the language design with adding new features and the browser vendors do an amazing job of implementing those features.

To see the current state of native support of any given feature in the browsers, see:

- http://caniuse.com/
- https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/

To see the support in Node versions, see:

- http://node.green/

To use modern syntax on platforms that don't support it natively, use Babel or TypeScript:

- https://babeljs.io/
- https://www.typescriptlang.org/

Comment: Here's a typescript version with a slight change to account for the way typescript does array spreading. https://gist.github.com/ssippe/1f92625532eef28be6974f898efb23ef

Comment: @rsp thanks a lot for really good answer. although I would like to ask you to improve it a bit to get rig of warning of shadowed variables (2 local vars `a` and 2 local vars `b`)

Comment: @ZuBB Thanks for letting me know about the linter problems. I added a version of the code that conforms to the Airbnb JavaScript Style Guide - see the updated question. Thanks!

Comment: "Don't code like it's 1995" - no need to be unpleasant, not everyone has caught up yet.

Comment: This is fine however fails when fed with `['a', 'b'], [1,2], [[9], [10]]` which will yield `[ [ 'a', 1, 9 ], [ 'a', 1, 10 ], [ 'a', 2, 9 ], [ 'a', 2, 10 ], [ 'b', 1, 9 ], [ 'b', 1, 10 ], [ 'b', 2, 9 ], [ 'b', 2, 10 ] ]` as a result. I mean won't keep the type of items of `[[9], [10]]`.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, and my new copy-pasta!

Indeed, this is basically the cornerstone of the Java vs Javascript language hatred debate.

Comment: Caveat emptor: This function will unpack the object from the array, if it's an array of one element. e.g. `cartesian(['a'], ['b'])` will return `[[ 'a', 'b']]`, but `cartesian([['a']])` will return `['a']`

Comment: This isn't quite right: `cartesian()` should be `[]`, not undefined. (Just as an empty sum is zero.)

Comment: Since we're using `...` already, shouldn't `[].concat(...[array])` become simply `[...array]`?

Comment: `const cartesian = (...arrays) => arrays.reduce(f)` will work, too

Comment: Don't code like it's 2017. Use `.flatMap` instead of `concat`+`map` :-)

Comment: @inker Thanks for your suggestion of using reduce - it helped me reduce (no pun intended!) my example to just one line! I updated the answer and gave you credit. Thanks!

Comment: @Bergi Very good point! :) With flatMap I reduced the answer to one line! I updated the answer and gave you credit. Thanks!

Comment: `a`, `b`, `d`, `e`, leave those names to your favourite JS mangler, meaningful ones could help to understand the logic here :) Plus, where has `c` gone? Nice one though, impressive solution!

Comment: @BrDaHa, the code works if you hack on a stringify the top elements of each array: `let stringified = arrays.map(arr => arr.map(JSON.stringify))` and then `cartesian(...stringified)`. Just parse after.

Comment: I note your latest `(...a) => a.reduce((a, b) => a.flatMap(d => b.map(e => [d, e].flat())));` does not work in the degenerate case of one argument -- rather than return a list of lists, it just returns the original input list.

Comment: For others looking for a version that works in TypeScript, see [comment from Sam's link](https://gist.github.com/ssippe/1f92625532eef28be6974f898efb23ef#gistcomment-3530882)

Comment: "Don't code like it's 1995" 
I do basically all the time...

Comment: The problem reported by @BrDaHa is solved by removing the .flat(), I do not understand the it's purpose.

Comment: `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` when there are too many items in the array due to the recursion.

Comment: "Don't code like it's 1995" - don't you think a non-functional implementation is easier to read? I've been staring at this admittedly beautiful one-liner for hours, and I still don't understand what's going on there.

Comment: @Bergi `flatMap` eats array values in the arrays. e.g. `cartesian(['a'], [['b']])` should evaluate to `[ ['a', ['b']] ]` but 2020 version now returns `[ ['a', 'b'] ]`

Comment: @Phrogz The problem is not with `flatMap` (which doesn't flatten recursively), it's using `[d, e].flat()` which should be `[...d, e]`. The whole expression should be `a.reduce((b, c) => b.flatMap(d => c.map(e => [...d, e])), [[]])`

Comment: This is a good example of the misconception that "clean code == fewer lines". Two lines of a headache, I don't trust this code one bit. The one-letter variable names makes the problem even worse. I don't see what's the issue with a 15-20 lines function that is actually readable.

Comment: I'm agree with @rbarreiro here the last .flat() is useless no?

Comment: Talks about `overly complicated` responses and proceeds to give a piece of code that has to be reverse-engineered to be understood

Comment: For anyone curious, this is how you convert this solution to Typescript: `const cartesian = <T extends unknown[]>(...a: { [K in keyof T]: T[K][] }) => a.reduce<T[]>((b, c) => b.flatMap((d) => c.map((e) => [...d, e] as T)), [[]] as unknown as T[]);`

Answer (score 60):

Here's a modified version of @viebel's code in plain Javascript, without using any library:

```js
function cartesianProduct(arr) {
    return arr.reduce(function(a,b){
        return a.map(function(x){
            return b.map(function(y){
                return x.concat([y]);
            })
        }).reduce(function(a,b){ return a.concat(b) },[])
    }, [[]])
}

var a = cartesianProduct([[1, 2,3], [4, 5,6], [7, 8], [9,10]]);
console.log(JSON.stringify(a));
```

Comment: Fails for cartesianProduct([[[1],[2],[3]], ['a', 'b'], [['gamma'], [['alpha']]], ['zii', 'faa']]) as it flattens ['gamma'] to 'gamma' and [['alpha']] to ['alpha']

Comment: because `.concat(y)` instead of `.concat([ y ])`

Comment: @Thankyou you can edit the answer directly instead of commenting, just did it so no need now :P

Answer (score 43):

The following efficient [generator function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*#Generatoren_und_Iteratoren_in_Firefox-Versionen_vor_26) returns the cartesian product of all given [iterables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols):

```js
// Generate cartesian product of given iterables:
function* cartesian(head, ...tail) {
  const remainder = tail.length > 0 ? cartesian(...tail) : [[]];
  for (let r of remainder) for (let h of head) yield [h, ...r];
}

// Example:
console.log(...cartesian([1, 2], [10, 20], [100, 200, 300]));
```

It accepts arrays, strings, sets and all other objects implementing the [iterable protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#The_iterable_protocol).

Following the specification of the [n-ary cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product#Finite_n-ary_product) it yields

- `[]` if one or more given iterables are empty, e.g. `[]` or `''`
- `[[a]]` if a single iterable containing a single value `a` is given.

All other cases are handled as expected as demonstrated by the following test cases:

```js
// Generate cartesian product of given iterables:
function* cartesian(head, ...tail) {
  const remainder = tail.length > 0 ? cartesian(...tail) : [[]];
  for (let r of remainder) for (let h of head) yield [h, ...r];
}

// Test cases:
console.log([...cartesian([])]);              // []
console.log([...cartesian([1])]);             // [[1]]
console.log([...cartesian([1, 2])]);          // [[1], [2]]

console.log([...cartesian([1], [])]);         // []
console.log([...cartesian([1, 2], [])]);      // []

console.log([...cartesian([1], [2])]);        // [[1, 2]]
console.log([...cartesian([1], [2], [3])]);   // [[1, 2, 3]]
console.log([...cartesian([1, 2], [3, 4])]);  // [[1, 3], [2, 3], [1, 4], [2, 4]]

console.log([...cartesian('')]);              // []
console.log([...cartesian('ab', 'c')]);       // [['a','c'], ['b', 'c']]
console.log([...cartesian([1, 2], 'ab')]);    // [[1, 'a'], [2, 'a'], [1, 'b'], [2, 'b']]

console.log([...cartesian(new Set())]);       // []
console.log([...cartesian(new Set([1]))]);    // [[1]]
console.log([...cartesian(new Set([1, 1]))]); // [[1]]
```

Comment: Do you mind to explain what's happening on this one? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks for teaching us a pretty wonderful example of using generator function + tail recursion + double-layer loops! But the position of the first for-loop in the code needs to be changed to make the order of the output sub-arrays correct. Fixed code: `function* cartesian(head, ...tail) { for (let h of head) { const remainder = tail.length > 0 ? cartesian(...tail) : [[]]; for (let r of remainder) yield [h, ...r] } }`

Comment: @ooo If you want to reproduce the order of the cartesian product tuples given by OP's comment, then your modification is correct. However, the order of the tuples within the product is usually not relevant, e.g. mathematically the result is an unordered set. I chose this order because it requires much less recursive calls and is therefore a bit more performant - I didn't run a benchmark though.

Comment: Erratum: In my comment above, "tail recursion" should be "recursion" (not a tail call in this case).

Comment: I am getting incorrect results passing in a Map, unless I clone the iterable beforehand with `Array.from` or `[...arg]`. Perhaps the problem is with me though.

Comment: I like this version the most, by all means. It uses a generator, it's just as compact as the most popular answer (and more compact than the accepted one) all while using readable variable names, and as the only answer I've tried so far it doesn't flatten nested arrays, which is an undesired side effect of the other answers! Only "drawback" is the different order, which to me really isn't.

Answer (score 31):

It seems the community thinks this to be trivial and/or easy to find a reference implementation. However, upon brief inspection I couldn't find one, … either that or maybe it's just that I like re-inventing the wheel or solving classroom-like programming problems. Either way its your lucky day:

```
function cartProd(paramArray) {
 
  function addTo(curr, args) {
    
    var i, copy, 
        rest = args.slice(1),
        last = !rest.length,
        result = [];
    
    for (i = 0; i < args[0].length; i++) {
      
      copy = curr.slice();
      copy.push(args[0][i]);
      
      if (last) {
        result.push(copy);
      
      } else {
        result = result.concat(addTo(copy, rest));
      }
    }
    
    return result;
  }
  
  
  return addTo([], Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
}


>> console.log(cartProd([1,2], [10,20], [100,200,300]));
>> [
     [1, 10, 100], [1, 10, 200], [1, 10, 300], [1, 20, 100], 
     [1, 20, 200], [1, 20, 300], [2, 10, 100], [2, 10, 200], 
     [2, 10, 300], [2, 20, 100], [2, 20, 200], [2, 20, 300]
   ]
```

Full reference implementation that's relatively efficient…

On efficiency: You could gain some by taking the if out of the loop and having 2 separate loops since it is technically constant and you'd be helping with branch prediction and all that mess, but that point is kind of moot in JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks @ckoz for your detailed answer. Why wouldn't you use the `reduce` function of array?

Comment: @viebel why do you want to use reduce?  for one, reduce has very poor support for older browsers (see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), and in any case does that crazy code from that other answer actually look readable to you? it doesn't to me. sure it's shorter, but once minified this code would be around the same length, easier to debug/optimize, secondly all those "reduce" solutions break down to the same thing, except they have a closure lookup (theoretically slower), it's also harder to design so it handles infinite sets...

Comment: I created a 2+ times faster and (imo) cleaner version: http://pastebin.com/YbhqZuf7 It achieves the speed boost by not using `result = result.concat(...)` and by not using `args.slice(1)`. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to find a way to get rid of `curr.slice()` and the recursion.

Comment: @Pauan nice job, nice reduction of hot-spots on the whole for in the league of a 10%-50% performance boost based on what I'm seeing.  I can't  speak as to the "cleanliness" though, I feel your version is actually more difficult to follow due to use of closure scope variables. But generally speaking, more performant code is harder to follow. I wrote the original version for readability, I wish I had more time so that I could engage you in a performance throw down ;) maybe later...

Comment: this really is one of those problems

Comment: @Pauan—it would be better to post your code as an answer here. Links rot. ;-)

Answer (score 25):

Here's a non-fancy, straightforward recursive solution:

```js
function cartesianProduct(a) { // a = array of array
  var i, j, l, m, a1, o = [];
  if (!a || a.length == 0) return a;

  a1 = a.splice(0, 1)[0]; // the first array of a
  a = cartesianProduct(a);
  for (i = 0, l = a1.length; i < l; i++) {
    if (a && a.length)
      for (j = 0, m = a.length; j < m; j++)
        o.push([a1[i]].concat(a[j]));
    else
      o.push([a1[i]]);
  }
  return o;
}

console.log(cartesianProduct([[1, 2], [10, 20], [100, 200, 300]]));
// [
//   [1,10,100],[1,10,200],[1,10,300],
//   [1,20,100],[1,20,200],[1,20,300],
//   [2,10,100],[2,10,200],[2,10,300],
//   [2,20,100],[2,20,200],[2,20,300]
// ]
```

Comment: This one turns out to be the most efficient pure JS code under this topic. It takes like ~600msecs to finish on 3 x 100 item arrays to produce an array of length 1M.

Comment: Works for cartesianProduct([[[1],[2],[3]], ['a', 'b'], [['gamma'], [['alpha']]], ['zii', 'faa']]); without flattening original values

Answer (score 21):

Here is a one-liner using the native ES2019 `flatMap`. No libraries needed, just a modern browser (or transpiler):

```
data.reduce((a, b) => a.flatMap(x => b.map(y => [...x, y])), [[]]);
```

It's essentially a modern version of viebel's answer, without lodash.

Comment: Sure no library was needed. But it's also, not the most readable code ever. It's a trade-off.

Comment: Readability has more to do in this case with my choice of using the spread operator I think, and not so much with the choice of not using a library. I don't think lodash leads to more readable code at all.

Comment: I prefer this answer over the 2020 version in rsp's top-voted answer, since this also works correctly when only one array is given, like `data = [["hello"]]`;

Comment: Readability has also to do with the variable names. `a`, `b`, `x` and `y` are all generic non-descriptive names. If actual descriptive names where used readability would improve. `arrays.reduce((product, array) => product.flatMap(combination => array.map(item => [...combination, item])), [[]])` Though like you can see it does become a bit longer.

Answer (score 14):

**functional programming**

This question is tagged *functional-programming* so let's take a look at the [*List monad*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(functional_programming)#Another_example:_List):

> One application for this monadic list is representing nondeterministic computation. `List` *can hold results for all execution paths* in an algorithm...

Well that sounds like a *perfect* fit for `cartesian`. JavaScript gives us `Array` and the monadic binding function is `Array.prototype.flatMap`, so let's put them to use -

```js
const cartesian = (...all) => {
  const loop = (t, a, ...more) =>
    a === undefined
      ? [ t ]
      : a.flatMap(x => loop([ ...t, x ], ...more))
  return loop([], ...all)
}

console.log(cartesian([1,2], [10,20], [100,200,300]))
```

```js
[1,10,100]
[1,10,200]
[1,10,300]
[1,20,100]
[1,20,200]
[1,20,300]
[2,10,100]
[2,10,200]
[2,10,300]
[2,20,100]
[2,20,200]
[2,20,300]
```

**more recursion**

Other recursive implementations include -

```js
const cartesian = (a, ...more) =>
  a == null
    ? [[]]
    : cartesian(...more).flatMap(c => a.map(v => [v,...c]))

for (const p of cartesian([1,2], [10,20], [100,200,300]))
  console.log(JSON.stringify(p))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%; top: 0; }
```

```js
[1,10,100]
[2,10,100]
[1,20,100]
[2,20,100]
[1,10,200]
[2,10,200]
[1,20,200]
[2,20,200]
[1,10,300]
[2,10,300]
[1,20,300]
[2,20,300]
```

Note the different order above. You can get [lexicographic order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order#Cartesian_products) by inverting the two loops. Be careful to avoid duplicating work by calling `cartesian` inside the loop like [Nick's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66979708/633183) -

```js
const bind = (x, f) => f(x)

const cartesian = (a, ...more) =>
  a == null
    ? [[]]
    : bind(cartesian(...more), r => a.flatMap(v => r.map(c => [v,...c])))

for (const p of cartesian([1,2], [10,20], [100,200,300]))
  console.log(JSON.stringify(p))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%; top: 0; }
```

```js
[1,10,100]
[1,10,200]
[1,10,300]
[1,20,100]
[1,20,200]
[1,20,300]
[2,10,100]
[2,10,200]
[2,10,300]
[2,20,100]
[2,20,200]
[2,20,300]
```

**generators**

Another option is to use generators. A generator is a good fit for combinatorics because the solution space can become very large. Generators offer lazy evaluation so they can be paused/resumed/canceled at any time -

```js
function* cartesian(a, ...more) {
  if (a == null) return yield []
  for (const v of a)
    for (const c of cartesian(...more)) // ⚠️
      yield [v, ...c]
}
  
for (const p of cartesian([1,2], [10,20], [100,200,300]))
  console.log(JSON.stringify(p))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%; top: 0; }
```

```js
[1,10,100]
[1,10,200]
[1,10,300]
[1,20,100]
[1,20,200]
[1,20,300]
[2,10,100]
[2,10,200]
[2,10,300]
[2,20,100]
[2,20,200]
[2,20,300]
```

Maybe you saw that we called `cartesian` in a loop in the generator. If you suspect that can be optimized, it can! Here we use a generic `tee` function that forks any iterator `n` times -

```js
function* cartesian(a, ...more) {
  if (a == null) return yield []
  for (const t of tee(cartesian(...more), a.length)) // ✅
    for (const v of a)
      for (const c of t) // ✅
        yield [v, ...c]
}
```

Where `tee` is implemented as -

```js
function tee(g, n = 2) {
  const memo = []
  function* iter(i) {
    while (true) {
      if (i >= memo.length) {
        const w = g.next()
        if (w.done) return
        memo.push(w.value)
      }
      else yield memo[i++]
    }
  }
  return Array.from(Array(n), _ => iter(0))
}
```

Even in small tests `cartesian` generator implemented with `tee` performs twice as fast.

Answer (score 13):

Here is a recursive way that uses an ECMAScript 2015 [generator function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator) so you don't have to create all of the tuples at once:

```js
function* cartesian() {
    let arrays = arguments;
    function* doCartesian(i, prod) {
        if (i == arrays.length) {
            yield prod;
        } else {
            for (let j = 0; j < arrays[i].length; j++) {
                yield* doCartesian(i + 1, prod.concat([arrays[i][j]]));
            }
        }
    }
    yield* doCartesian(0, []);
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(Array.from(cartesian([1,2],[10,20],[100,200,300]))));
console.log(JSON.stringify(Array.from(cartesian([[1],[2]],[10,20],[100,200,300]))));
```

Comment: This won't work when one of the arrays have array items such as `cartesian([[1],[2]],[10,20],[100,200,300])`

Comment: @Redu Answer has been updated to support array arguments.

Comment: Yes `.concat()` built in spread operator sometimes might become deceitful.

Answer (score 12):

This is a pure ES6 solution using [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

```js
function cartesianProduct(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((a, b) =>
    a.map(x => b.map(y => x.concat(y)))
    .reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b), []), [[]]);
}

var arr = [[1, 2], [10, 20], [100, 200, 300]];
console.log(JSON.stringify(cartesianProduct(arr)));
```

Answer (score 9):

Using a typical backtracking with ES6 generators,

```js
function cartesianProduct(...arrays) {
  let current = new Array(arrays.length);
  return (function* backtracking(index) {
    if(index == arrays.length) yield current.slice();
    else for(let num of arrays[index]) {
      current[index] = num;
      yield* backtracking(index+1);
    }
  })(0);
}
for (let item of cartesianProduct([1,2],[10,20],[100,200,300])) {
  console.log('[' + item.join(', ') + ']');
}
```

```css
div.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100%; }
```

Below there is a similar version compatible with older browsers.

```js
function cartesianProduct(arrays) {
  var result = [],
      current = new Array(arrays.length);
  (function backtracking(index) {
    if(index == arrays.length) return result.push(current.slice());
    for(var i=0; i<arrays[index].length; ++i) {
      current[index] = arrays[index][i];
      backtracking(index+1);
    }
  })(0);
  return result;
}
cartesianProduct([[1,2],[10,20],[100,200,300]]).forEach(function(item) {
  console.log('[' + item.join(', ') + ']');
});
```

```css
div.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100%; }
```

Answer (score 8):

A coffeescript version with lodash:

```
_ = require("lodash")
cartesianProduct = ->
    return _.reduceRight(arguments, (a,b) ->
        _.flatten(_.map(a,(x) -> _.map b, (y) -> x.concat(y)), true)
    , [ [] ])
```

Answer (score 8):

A single line approach, for better reading with indentations.

```
result = data.reduce(
    (a, b) => a.reduce(
        (r, v) => r.concat(b.map(w => [].concat(v, w))),
        []
    )
);
```

It takes a single array with arrays of wanted cartesian items.

```js
var data = [[1, 2], [10, 20], [100, 200, 300]],
    result = data.reduce((a, b) => a.reduce((r, v) => r.concat(b.map(w => [].concat(v, w))), []));

console.log(result.map(a => a.join(' ')));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I had to add a guard statement to correctly handle the case where the array has a single element: `if (arr.length === 1) return arr[0].map(el => [el]);`

Answer (score 5):

Another, even more simplified, 2021-style answer using only reduce, map, and concat methods:

```js
const cartesian = (...arr) => arr.reduce((a,c) => a.map(e => c.map(f => e.concat([f]))).reduce((a,c) => a.concat(c), []), [[]]);

console.log(cartesian([1, 2], [10, 20], [100, 200, 300]));
```

Comment: in all honesty - I have no idea what's happening here, but it seems to be working fine even for complex objects (unlike some solutions that worked only for strings). I'd appreciate you using some more descriptive names (as opposed to a, c, f, etc) - especially that they overlap each other. What I mean by that is that they have different scopes, but same names, so it's hard to understand.

Comment: ps. typescript types wouldn't hurt as well. so `Array<Array<any>>` as input (and so on for other variables) as opposed to... well, nothing

Answer (score 4):

In my particular setting, the "old-fashioned" approach seemed to be more efficient than the methods based on more modern features. Below is the code (including a small comparison with other solutions posted in this thread by @rsp and @sebnukem) should it prove useful to someone else as well.

The idea is following. Let's say we are constructing the outer product of `N` arrays, `a_1,...,a_N` each of which has `m_i` components. The outer product of these arrays has `M=m_1*m_2*...*m_N` elements and we can identify each of them with a `N-`dimensional vector the components of which are positive integers and `i`-th component is strictly bounded from above by `m_i`. For example, the vector `(0, 0, ..., 0)` would correspond to the particular combination within which one takes the first element from each array, while `(m_1-1, m_2-1, ..., m_N-1)` is identified with the combination where one takes the last element from each array. Thus in order to construct all `M` combinations, the function below consecutively constructs all such vectors and for each of them identifies the corresponding combination of the elements of the input arrays.

```
function cartesianProduct(){
    const N = arguments.length;

    var arr_lengths = Array(N);
    var digits = Array(N);
    var num_tot = 1;
    for(var i = 0; i < N; ++i){
        const len = arguments[i].length;
        if(!len){
            num_tot = 0;
            break;
        }
        digits[i] = 0;
        num_tot *= (arr_lengths[i] = len);
    }

    var ret = Array(num_tot);
    for(var num = 0; num < num_tot; ++num){

        var item = Array(N);
        for(var j = 0; j < N; ++j){ item[j] = arguments[j][digits[j]]; }
        ret[num] = item;

        for(var idx = 0; idx < N; ++idx){
            if(digits[idx] == arr_lengths[idx]-1){
                digits[idx] = 0;
            }else{
                digits[idx] += 1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
let _f = (a, b) => [].concat(...a.map(a => b.map(b => [].concat(a, b))));
let cartesianProduct_rsp = (a, b, ...c) => b ? cartesianProduct_rsp(_f(a, b), ...c) : a;
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function cartesianProduct_sebnukem(a) {
    var i, j, l, m, a1, o = [];
    if (!a || a.length == 0) return a;

    a1 = a.splice(0, 1)[0];
    a = cartesianProduct_sebnukem(a);
    for (i = 0, l = a1.length; i < l; i++) {
        if (a && a.length) for (j = 0, m = a.length; j < m; j++)
            o.push([a1[i]].concat(a[j]));
        else
            o.push([a1[i]]);
    }
    return o;
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
const L = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
const args = [L, L, L, L, L, L];

let fns = {
    'cartesianProduct': function(args){ return cartesianProduct(...args); },
    'cartesianProduct_rsp': function(args){ return cartesianProduct_rsp(...args); },
    'cartesianProduct_sebnukem': function(args){ return cartesianProduct_sebnukem(args); }
};

Object.keys(fns).forEach(fname => {
    console.time(fname);
    const ret = fns[fname](args);
    console.timeEnd(fname);
});
```

with `node v6.12.2`, I get following timings:

```
cartesianProduct: 427.378ms
cartesianProduct_rsp: 1710.829ms
cartesianProduct_sebnukem: 593.351ms
```

Comment: good stuff, sometimes a cartesian products may involve a HUGE input/output and most recursion based method would fail. Even some method that put a crazy large object (>4GB) in the memory would also fail too if not using generators. This ordinary method is the way to go.

Answer (score 4):

For those who needs TypeScript (reimplemented @Danny's answer)

```js
/**
 * Calculates "Cartesian Product" sets.
 * @example
 *   cartesianProduct([[1,2], [4,8], [16,32]])
 *   Returns:
 *   [
 *     [1, 4, 16],
 *     [1, 4, 32],
 *     [1, 8, 16],
 *     [1, 8, 32],
 *     [2, 4, 16],
 *     [2, 4, 32],
 *     [2, 8, 16],
 *     [2, 8, 32]
 *   ]
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/36234242/1955709
 * @see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product
 * @param arr {T[][]}
 * @returns {T[][]}
 */
function cartesianProduct<T> (arr: T[][]): T[][] {
  return arr.reduce((a, b) => {
    return a.map(x => {
      return b.map(y => {
        return x.concat(y)
      })
    }).reduce((c, d) => c.concat(d), [])
  }, [[]] as T[][])
}
```

Comment: This only supports homogeneous types; where all values in the arrays are of the same type.

Answer (score 4):

Modern JavaScript in just a few lines. No external libraries or dependencies like Lodash.

```js
function cartesian(...arrays) {
  return arrays.reduce((a, b) => a.flatMap(x => b.map(y => x.concat([y]))), [ [] ]);
}

console.log(
  cartesian([1, 2], [10, 20], [100, 200, 300])
    .map(arr => JSON.stringify(arr))
    .join('\n')
);
```

Answer (score 4):

You could [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) the 2D array. Use [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) on the accumulator array to get `acc.length x curr.length` number of combinations in each loop. `[].concat(c, n)` is used because `c` is a number in the first iteration and an array afterwards.

```js
const data = [ [1, 2], [10, 20], [100, 200, 300] ];

const output = data.reduce((acc, curr) =>
  acc.flatMap(c => curr.map(n => [].concat(c, n)))
)

console.log(JSON.stringify(output))
```

(This is based on [Nina Scholz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50631472/3082296))

Answer (score 4):

Here's a recursive one-liner that works using only [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) and [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
const inp = [
  [1, 2],
  [10, 20],
  [100, 200, 300]
];

const cartesian = (first, ...rest) => 
  rest.length ? first.flatMap(v => cartesian(...rest).map(c => [v].concat(c))) 
              : first;

console.log(cartesian(...inp));
```

Answer (score 3):

A few of the answers under this topic fail when any of the input arrays contains an array item. You you better check that.

Anyways no need for underscore, lodash whatsoever. I believe this one should do it with pure JS ES6, as functional as it gets.

This piece of code uses a reduce and a nested map, simply to get the cartesian product of two arrays however the second array comes from a recursive call to the same function with one less array; hence..  `a[0].cartesian(...a.slice(1))`

```js
Array.prototype.cartesian = function(...a){
  return a.length ? this.reduce((p,c) => (p.push(...a[0].cartesian(...a.slice(1)).map(e => a.length > 1 ? [c,...e] : [c,e])),p),[])
                  : this;
};

var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    brr = [1,2,3],
    crr = [[9],[8],[7]];
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr.cartesian(brr,crr)));
```

Answer (score 3):

## No libraries needed! :)

Needs arrow functions though and probably not that efficient. :/

```js
const flatten = (xs) => 
    xs.flat(Infinity)

const binaryCartesianProduct = (xs, ys) =>
    xs.map((xi) => ys.map((yi) => [xi, yi])).flat()

const cartesianProduct = (...xss) =>
    xss.reduce(binaryCartesianProduct, [[]]).map(flatten)
      
console.log(cartesianProduct([1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3]))
```

Answer (score 3):

A more readable implementation

```js
function productOfTwo(one, two) {
  return one.flatMap(x => two.map(y => [].concat(x, y)));
}

function product(head = [], ...tail) {
  if (tail.length === 0) return head;
  return productOfTwo(head, product(...tail));
}

const test = product(
  [1, 2, 3],
  ['a', 'b']
);

console.log(JSON.stringify(test));
```

Comment: `[].concat(x, y)` could also be `[x, y].flat()`. Also, one could write `[[1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b']].reduce(productOfTwo)` to avoid recursion.

Answer (score 3):

Similar in spirit to others, but highly readable imo.

```
const productOfTwo = (a, b) => a.flatMap(c => b.map(d => [c, d].flat()));
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['+', '-'], [1, 2, 3]].reduce(productOfTwo);
```

Answer (score 2):

For those happy with a ramda solution:

```
import { xprod, flatten } from 'ramda';

const cartessian = (...xs) => xs.reduce(xprod).map(flatten)
```

Or the same without dependencies and two lego blocks for free (`xprod` and `flatten`):

```
const flatten = xs => xs.flat();

const xprod = (xs, ys) => xs.flatMap(x => ys.map(y => [x, y]));

const cartessian = (...xs) => xs.reduce(xprod).map(flatten);
```

Answer (score 1):

A non-recursive approach that adds the ability to filter and modify the products before actually adding them to the result set.

Note: the use of `.map` rather than `.forEach`. In some browsers, `.map` runs faster.

```js
function crossproduct(arrays, rowtest, rowaction) {
  // Calculate the number of elements needed in the result
  var result_elems = 1,
    row_size = arrays.length;
  arrays.map(function(array) {
    result_elems *= array.length;
  });
  var temp = new Array(result_elems),
    result = [];

  // Go through each array and add the appropriate
  // element to each element of the temp
  var scale_factor = result_elems;
  arrays.map(function(array) {
    var set_elems = array.length;
    scale_factor /= set_elems;
    for (var i = result_elems - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      temp[i] = (temp[i] ? temp[i] : []);
      var pos = i / scale_factor % set_elems;
      // deal with floating point results for indexes,
      // this took a little experimenting
      if (pos < 1 || pos % 1 <= .5) {
        pos = Math.floor(pos);
      } else {
        pos = Math.min(array.length - 1, Math.ceil(pos));
      }
      temp[i].push(array[pos]);
      if (temp[i].length === row_size) {
        var pass = (rowtest ? rowtest(temp[i]) : true);
        if (pass) {
          if (rowaction) {
            result.push(rowaction(temp[i]));
          } else {
            result.push(temp[i]);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });
  return result;
}

console.log(
crossproduct([[1, 2], [10, 20], [100, 200, 300]],null,null)
)
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Perhaps add calls with rowtests and  rowactions ? Also where did you see forEach is slower than map?

Answer (score 1):

Just for a choice a real simple implementation using array's `reduce`:

```
const array1 = ["day", "month", "year", "time"];
const array2 = ["from", "to"];
const process = (one, two) => [one, two].join(" ");

const product = array1.reduce((result, one) => result.concat(array2.map(two => process(one, two))), []);
```

Answer (score 1):

**A simple "mind and visually friendly" solution.**

[image]

---

```
// t = [i, length]

const moveThreadForwardAt = (t, tCursor) => {
  if (tCursor < 0)
    return true; // reached end of first array

  const newIndex = (t[tCursor][0] + 1) % t[tCursor][1];
  t[tCursor][0] = newIndex;

  if (newIndex == 0)
    return moveThreadForwardAt(t, tCursor - 1);

  return false;
}

const cartesianMult = (...args) => {
  let result = [];
  const t = Array.from(Array(args.length)).map((x, i) => [0, args[i].length]);
  let reachedEndOfFirstArray = false;

  while (false == reachedEndOfFirstArray) {
    result.push(t.map((v, i) => args[i][v[0]]));

    reachedEndOfFirstArray = moveThreadForwardAt(t, args.length - 1);
  }

  return result;
}

// cartesianMult(
//   ['a1', 'b1', 'c1'],
//   ['a2', 'b2'],
//   ['a3', 'b3', 'c3'],
//   ['a4', 'b4']
// );

console.log(cartesianMult(
  ['a1'],
  ['a2', 'b2'],
  ['a3', 'b3']
));
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another implementation. Not the shortest or fancy, but fast:

```
function cartesianProduct() {
    var arr = [].slice.call(arguments),
        intLength = arr.length,
        arrHelper = [1],
        arrToReturn = [];

    for (var i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        arrHelper.unshift(arrHelper[0] * arr[i].length);
    }

    for (var i = 0, l = arrHelper[0]; i < l; i++) {
        arrToReturn.push([]);
        for (var j = 0; j < intLength; j++) {
            arrToReturn[i].push(arr[j][(i / arrHelper[j + 1] | 0) % arr[j].length]);
        }
    }

    return arrToReturn;
}
```

Comment: This works for large arrays, unlike the one-liner.

Answer (score 1):

A simple, modified version of @viebel's code in plain Javascript:

```
function cartesianProduct(...arrays) {
  return arrays.reduce((a, b) => {
    return [].concat(...a.map(x => {
      const next = Array.isArray(x) ? x : [x];
      return [].concat(b.map(y => next.concat(...[y])));
    }));
  });
}

const product = cartesianProduct([1, 2], [10, 20], [100, 200, 300]);

console.log(product);
/*
[ [ 1, 10, 100 ],
  [ 1, 10, 200 ],
  [ 1, 10, 300 ],
  [ 1, 20, 100 ],
  [ 1, 20, 200 ],
  [ 1, 20, 300 ],
  [ 2, 10, 100 ],
  [ 2, 10, 200 ],
  [ 2, 10, 300 ],
  [ 2, 20, 100 ],
  [ 2, 20, 200 ],
  [ 2, 20, 300 ] ];
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

```
f=(a,b,c)=>a.flatMap(ai=>b.flatMap(bi=>c.map(ci=>[ai,bi,ci])))
```

This is for 3 arrays.
Some answers gave a way for any number of arrays.
This can easily contract or expand to less or more arrays.
I needed combinations of one set with repetitions, so I could have used:

```
f(a,a,a)
```

but used:

```
f=(a,b,c)=>a.flatMap(a1=>a.flatMap(a2=>a.map(a3=>[a1,a2,a3])))
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that nobody posted a solution that allows a function to be passed to process each combination, so here is my solution:

```
const _ = require('lodash')

function combinations(arr, f, xArr = []) {
    return arr.length>1 
    ? _.flatMap(arr[0], x => combinations(arr.slice(1), f, xArr.concat(x)))
    : arr[0].map(x => f(...xArr.concat(x)))
}

// use case
const greetings = ["Hello", "Goodbye"]
const places = ["World", "Planet"]
const punctuationMarks = ["!", "?"]
combinations([greetings,places,punctuationMarks], (greeting, place, punctuationMark) => `${greeting} ${place}${punctuationMark}`)
  .forEach(row => console.log(row))
```

Output:

```
Hello World!
Hello World?
Hello Planet!
Hello Planet?
Goodbye World!
Goodbye World?
Goodbye Planet!
Goodbye Planet?
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var chars = ['A', 'B', 'C']
var nums = [1, 2, 3]

var cartesianProduct = function() {
  return _.reduce(arguments, function(a, b) {
    return _.flatten(_.map(a, function(x) {
      return _.map(b, function(y) {
        return x.concat(y);
      });
    }), true);
  }, [
    []
  ]);
};

console.log(cartesianProduct(chars, nums))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Just converted [@dummersl's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22135232/1766716) answer from CoffeScript to JavaScript. It just works.

```
var chars = ['A', 'B', 'C']
var nums = [1, 2, 3]

var cartesianProduct = function() {
  return _.reduce(arguments, function(a, b) {
    return _.flatten(_.map(a, function(x) {
      return _.map(b, function(y) {
        return x.concat(y);
      });
    }), true);
  }, [[]]);
};

console.log( cartesianProduct(chars, nums) )
```

Answer (score 0):

For the record

Here it goes my version of it. I made it using the simplest javascript iterator "for()", so it's compatible on every case and has the best performance.

```
function cartesian(arrays){
    var quant = 1, counters = [], retArr = [];

    // Counts total possibilities and build the counters Array;
    for(var i=0;i<arrays.length;i++){
        counters[i] = 0;
        quant *= arrays[i].length;
    }

    // iterate all possibilities
    for(var i=0,nRow;i<quant;i++){
        nRow = [];
        for(var j=0;j<counters.length;j++){
            if(counters[j] < arrays[j].length){
                nRow.push(arrays[j][counters[j]]);
            } else { // in case there is no such an element it restarts the current counter
                counters[j] = 0;
                nRow.push(arrays[j][counters[j]]);
            }
            counters[j]++;
        }
        retArr.push(nRow);
    }
    return retArr;
}
```

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

**2021 version of David Tang's great [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4331713/12496886)**
Also inspired with Neil Mountford's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15301002/12496886)

- fast (faster than accepted answer by 95%)
- works with any data types

```js
const getAllCombinations = (arraysToCombine) => {
  const divisors = [];
  let combinationsCount = 1;
  for (let i = arraysToCombine.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      divisors[i] = divisors[i + 1] ? divisors[i + 1] * arraysToCombine[i + 1].length : 1;
      combinationsCount *= (arraysToCombine[i].length || 1);
  }

  const getCombination = (n, arrays, divisors) => arrays.reduce((acc, arr, i) => {
      acc.push(arr[Math.floor(n / divisors[i]) % arr.length]);
      return acc;
  }, []);

  const combinations = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < combinationsCount; i++) {
      combinations.push(getCombination(i, arraysToCombine, divisors));
  }
  return combinations;
};

console.log(getAllCombinations([['a', 'b'], ['c', 'z'], ['d', 'e', 'f']]));
```

Benchmarks: https://jsbench.me/gdkmxhm36d/1

Comment: The way I read these benchmark results, this version is tremendously slower than the one in the [highest-voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43053803/1243641).

Comment: @ScottSauyet thanks for you comment. I updated the benchmark, now results are legit. The problem was that this method accepts single array of arrays as an argument and the highest-voted answer accepts any count of arrays as arguments.

Answer (score -1):

Plain JS brute force approach that takes an array of arrays as input.

```
var cartesian = function(arrays) {
    var product = [];
    var precals = [];
    var length = arrays.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
        return acc * curr.length
    }, 1);
    for (var i = 0; i < arrays.length; i++) {
        var array = arrays[i];
        var mod = array.length;
        var div = i > 0 ? precals[i - 1].div * precals[i - 1].mod : 1;
        precals.push({
            div: div,
            mod: mod
        });
    }
    for (var j = 0; j < length; j++) {
        var item = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < arrays.length; i++) {
            var array = arrays[i];
            var precal = precals[i];
            var k = (~~(j / precal.div)) % precal.mod;
            item.push(array[k]);
        }
        product.push(item);
    }
    return product;
};

cartesian([
    [1],
    [2, 3]
]);

cartesian([
    [1],
    [2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6]
]);
```

Answer (score -1):

I like this for readability purposes..

```
const _getPotentialArrayCombos = (arrayOfArrays)=>{
    let potentialArrayCombos
    for(const array of arrayOfArrays){
        if(!potentialArrayCombos){
            potentialArrayCombos=[]
            for(const value of array){
                potentialArrayCombos.push([value])
            }
        }else{
            const newPotentialArrayCombos = []
            for(const combo of potentialArrayCombos){
                for(const value of array){
                    newPotentialArrayCombos.push([...combo,value])
                }
            }
            potentialArrayCombos = newPotentialArrayCombos 
        }
    }
    return potentialArrayCombos
}
```